# Unity Android app critical crash when it's set as default home (when home button is pressed)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, crash, android-homebutton

I'm developing an Android application with Unity and one of the requirements is that my app asks for a set default home in the device.

I was looking everywhere and I read many tutorials in order to do that.

But when the screen of defaults home apps are showed and after that the home button is pressed,  my app crash!!

showing the next output in the logcat

[UPDATE] Full output

```
08-20 12:38:06.240 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{c4655f4 token=android.os.BinderProxy@6db211d {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow@7b02d0f
08-20 12:38:06.240 4037-4037/? V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =ViewRoot{29d9142 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6b26f8c I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-1024,600}
08-20 12:38:07.264 716-1837/? I/HwWindowManagerService: setFocusedApp token: Token{141f913 ActivityRecord{b19c94d u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t207}} requestedOrientation: 6
08-20 12:38:07.287 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} startsNotResumed=false
08-20 12:38:07.287 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@4021d63, appName=com.companyname.appname, pkg=com.companyname.appname, comp={com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.companyname.appname-1/base.apk
08-20 12:38:07.365 4037-4037/? D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921
08-20 12:38:07.365 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
08-20 12:38:07.366 4037-4037/? D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
08-20 12:38:07.366 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
08-20 12:38:07.368 4037-4037/? D/ViewRootImpl: disable hardware acceleration by APP!!!, this = ViewRoot{b2a951b com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity,ident = 1}
08-20 12:38:07.369 716-1589/? V/HwPhoneWindowManager: updateSystemUiColorLw window=Window{94bb65f u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity},EmuiStyle=0,StatusBarColor=0xff757575,NavigationBarColor=0xff000000
08-20 12:38:07.371 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} with isForward=true
08-20 12:38:07.372 4037-4037/? V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{b2a951b com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity,ident = 1}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7b20bd2 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
08-20 12:38:07.372 4037-4037/? V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
08-20 12:38:07.372 4037-4037/? D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{ac08b88 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1af0921 {com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}}
08-20 12:38:07.458 716-739/? I/ActivityManager: [AppLaunch] Displayed Displayed com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +179ms
08-20 12:38:07.458 716-739/? D/ActivityManager: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_LaunchTime:com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity:179:148820910
08-20 12:38:07.469 716-1842/? I/HwWindowManagerService: setAppOrientation token: Token{141f913 ActivityRecord{b19c94d u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t207}} requestedOrientation: 0
08-20 12:38:07.487 4037-4359/? E/CRASH: pid: 4037, tid: 4359, name: UnityMain  >>> com.companyname.appname <<<
08-20 12:38:08.206 4037-4359/? E/CRASH:     #00  pc 006a72c0  /data/app/com.companyname.appname-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
08-20 12:38:08.207 4037-4359/? E/CRASH:     #01  pc 006a75f4  /data/app/com.companyname.appname-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
08-20 12:38:08.207 4037-4359/? E/CRASH:     #02  pc 006a3fc4  /data/app/com.companyname.appname-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
08-20 12:38:08.232 4037-4359/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
    Process: com.companyname.appname, PID: 4037
    java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain]
    Unity version     : 2018.4.4f1
    Device model      : HUAWEI BG2-W09
    Device fingerprint: HUAWEI/BG2/hwbg2:6.0/HuaweiBAGGIO2/C331B005:user/release-keys

    Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
    Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/BG2/hwbg2:6.0/HuaweiBAGGIO2/C331B005:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    pid: 4037, tid: 4359, name: UnityMain  >>> com.companyname.appname <<<
        r0 00000000  r1 00000001  r2 b1882a30  r3 b1882930
        r4 00000001  r5 00000094  r6 00000001  r7 12df8090
        r8 12e2d0a0  r9 902db700  sl 12ca7700  fp b18826bc
        ip b1882a90  sp b1882490  lr 9dbc5d48  pc 9da1f2c0  cpsr 00001107

        at libunity.006a72c0(Native Method)
        at libunity.006a75f4(Native Method)
        at libunity.006a3fc4(Native Method)
        at base.oatexec(oatexec)
08-20 12:38:08.250 716-727/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
08-20 12:38:08.251 716-727/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
08-20 12:38:08.369 716-716/? V/WindowManager: Skipping AppWindowToken{aad0750 token=Token{141f913 ActivityRecord{b19c94d u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t207}}} -- going to hide
08-20 12:38:08.385 716-716/? V/WindowManager: Skipping AppWindowToken{aad0750 token=Token{141f913 ActivityRecord{b19c94d u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t207}}} -- going to hide
08-20 12:38:08.387 716-931/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '56b8c04 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-20 12:38:08.388 716-931/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '56b8c04 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-20 12:38:08.391 716-931/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '94bb65f com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-20 12:38:08.391 716-931/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '94bb65f com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-20 12:38:08.411 716-730/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{94bb65f u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
08-20 12:38:08.411 716-730/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '94bb65f com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
08-20 12:38:08.418 716-2040/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{56b8c04 u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
08-20 12:38:08.418 716-2040/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '56b8c04 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
08-20 12:38:08.532 716-1708/? W/WindowState: Failed to report 'resized' to the client of Window{94bb65f u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}, removing this window.
08-20 12:38:08.541 189-1622/? D/SurfaceFlinger:     remove: com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
08-20 12:38:09.350 2107-2131/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.IconCache, cacheLocked  Utilities.createIconBitmap entry.title = Liberarte ComponentName:ComponentInfo{com.creators.liberarte/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} user:UserHandle{0}
08-20 12:38:10.094 2107-2131/? I/HwResources: load icon id : 7f020001, pkgName : com.unity3d.genericremote
08-20 12:38:10.109 2107-2131/? I/HwResources: icon : com.unity3d.genericremote found in app
08-20 12:38:10.112 2107-2131/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.IconCache, cacheLocked  Utilities.createIconBitmap entry.title = Unity Remote 5 ComponentName:ComponentInfo{com.unity3d.genericremote/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} user:UserHandle{0}
08-20 12:38:10.238 2107-2131/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.IconCache, cacheLocked  Utilities.createIconBitmap entry.title = Word Travels ComponentName:ComponentInfo{com.funstudio.wordtravels/com.funstudio.wordtravels.UnityPlayerActivity} user:UserHandle{0}
08-20 12:38:10.273 2107-2131/? I/HwLauncher: Model  LauncherModel loadHotseatAndDeskTop :this Item is SDApps,loading it until loadSDApps. intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity } sIsSupportSDInstall = true
08-20 12:38:10.519 2107-2131/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.IconCache, cacheLocked  Utilities.createIconBitmap entry.title = Vicente Lopez ComponentName:ComponentInfo{com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} user:UserHandle{0}
08-20 12:38:10.939 2107-2131/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher.IconCache, cacheLocked  Utilities.createIconBitmap entry.title = Dino Tim ComponentName:ComponentInfo{com.EducaGames.DinoTim/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} user:UserHandle{0}
08-20 12:38:18.254 716-732/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4c4e147 u0 com.companyname.appname/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t204 f}
```

I tried many things.

Change the unity version.
Select different levels Target API for compile

Currently, I'm working with Unity 2018.4.4f1

This is set in my manifest file...

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Finally, I could find a temporal solution doing this.. the error keeps showing sometimes and I don't know what is the reason.

Sometimes when another app is open and the home button is pressed this error occurs again

Does anyone happen the same?

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer somewhere in C code, in the libunity library.  Beyond that, you've cut off any more useful parts of the stack trace.

Comment: Hello Gabe Sechan.. ok but I do not touch that file, if you can create an empty project in unity and just add this lines in your manifest file **<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />** run in your device and after that press home button the error occurs.

Comment: That's the unity library. If you're making Ann app that uses unity, you're using it. Most likely you're passing it bad data somewhere.

Comment: yes the app that I making is made in Unity.. but as I said before, when you create an empty project with Unity and add those lines, this error occurs, maybe unity try to access to some location inside the libunity library, I don't really know how to track the error